# Expectation of dual norm induced by probability measure

Tags: pr.probability, convex-geometry

Let $\mu$ be a probability measure supported on the unit sphere $\mathbb{S}^{d-1}$. Assuming that $\mu$ is even and not supported on any great subsphere, its cosine transform $w \in \mathbb{R}^d \mapsto  \|w\|=\mathbb{E}_{x \sim \mu}[|\langle w,x \rangle|]$ defines a norm on $\mathbb{R}^d$. A [classic result](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1969-145-00/S0002-9947-1969-0256265-X/S0002-9947-1969-0256265-X.pdf) of Bolker observes that such norms are in correspondence with $d$-dimensional subspaces of $L^1$, by mapping $w$ to the random variable $\langle w,x \rangle$ for $x \sim \mu$. I would like to upper bound the expected dual norm
$$
\mathbb{E}_{x \sim \mu}[\|x\|_*] = \mathbb{E}_{x \sim \mu}\left[\sup_{\|w\| \leq 1} \langle w,x \rangle\right]
$$
in terms of $d$. Any polynomial bound would do, but I actually suspect that an exact bound of $d$ holds, achieved by $\mu = \frac{1}{d} \sum_{i=1}^d e_i$ (when $\|w\|=\frac{1}{d}\|w\|_1$ and $\|x\|_* = d\|x\|_\infty$). It may be useful to consider the norm induced by the covariance matrix $\Sigma_\mu$, $\mathbb{E}_{x \sim \mu}[\langle w,x \rangle^2]^{1/2} = \langle w, \Sigma_\mu w \rangle^{1/2}$, which serves as an upper bound for $\|\cdot\|$ by Jensen's inequality.